# Subscription in Redux Weird behaviour of subscription in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux at the moment. Code shared below is independent of React, so React integration is out of consideration.

Below is redux-basics.js which has **Reducer, Store , Action and Subscription** Section

```
const redux = require('redux');
const createStore =  redux.createStore;
// Note : Store Creation is actually dependent on Reducer Thats why reducer must be created first.
// Reducer
const initialState = {  counter : 0}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState,action) => {

     if(action.type === 'INCR_COUNTER'){
         return  {  ...state, 
            counter : state.counter + 1 }
     }

     if(action.type === 'ADD_COUNTER'){
        return  {  ...state, 
           counter : state.counter + action.value }
    }


    return state;
}
// Store 
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log(store.getState())


// Subscription
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(" SUbscription " , store.getState()  );
})



// Despatching an Action 
store.dispatch({type : "INCR_COUNTER"});
store.dispatch({type: "ADD_COUNTER",
 value : 10
});



console.log(store.getState());
```

Then I get output like below ( **And which is correct!** ):

```
Ps-MBP:redux--01-start pramod$ node redux-basics.js 
{ counter: 0 }
 SUbscription  { counter: 1 }
 SUbscription  { counter: 11 }
{ counter: 11 }
```

But when I move listeners below dispatch method then subscriptions wont work? I am trying what I am missing or why is so? Code I am doing is like below: ( **I thought it will print subscription method output, but it isn't**)

```
// Despatching an Action 
store.dispatch({type : "INCR_COUNTER"});
store.dispatch({type: "ADD_COUNTER",
 value : 10
});

// Subscription
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(" SUbscription " , store.getState()  );
})



console.log(store.getState())
```

After making above code shifting code output is as below:

```
Pramod:redux--01-start pramod$ node redux-basics.js 
{ counter: 0 }
{ counter: 11 }
```

Any hint/idea why is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dispatching actions before adding the subscribe listener. Code is executed sequentially so when the flow reaches the action dispatching part there is no subscription defined to output the state.